# TypeError: "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'" error on Math Modeling code

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np 
A=[]
B=[]
def p_d():
    for x in range(1,31):
        for y in range(1,x):
            a=np.math.factorial(x)
            b=np.math.factorial(y)*np.math.factorial(x-y)
            c=a/b
            p=.9
            q=.1
            d=p**y
            e=q**(x-y)
            f=c*d*e
            A.append(f)
def p_B():
    g=p_d()
    h=1-p_d()
    for p in range(1,61):
        i=np.math.factorial(126)
        j=np.math.factorial(p)*np.math.factorial(126-p)
        k=i/j
        m=126-p
        l=k*g**x*h**m
        l.append(B)
z=sum(B,1)
```

Hey everyone! I am working on a piece of code for my Math Modeling course, and I thought I had the correct code, but in line 18, I am getting a error that says "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'". I tried looking online, but I have had no luck determining how I am supposed to change my code to work. I am trying to get it to take a total of a binomial distribution, where I am trying to determine the probability of success of a bomb attacking a base, and the number of missiles necessary to defend against the bomb. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! I am using Python 3 if that helps.

Comment: `p_d()` evaluates to `None` because it doesn't contain any `return` statements.

Comment: `p_d()` doesnt return anything but you're trying to subtract it from `1`.

Comment: Did you identify which line had the problem? Which variable had the value `None`?  Then look back to where that variable was created.  That's where the actual problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This line `h=1-p_d()` makes no sense. `-` is a binary operator that takes two arguments, where function `p_d()` returns nothing. `1 - None` doesn't make sense...

Comment: Thanks! I think that's the problem. I'm not too strong at coding. I am going to try and fix it.